# How to run a modal if the user isn't logged in?

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, ejs

I'm trying to have a modal activate if the user isn't logged in and trying to click something for authorized users.

on the server side I know if I want to check if I am authenticated, I simply write: `if(req.isAuthenticated())` and res.render a page. However, in my case, I simply want to trigger a modal prompting the user to sign in. So I need to do it on the client's end. So how do I do this from the client-side? Below is the code I came up with but isAuthenticated variable does not appear to be the answer.

**HTML:**

```
<a id="chkLog"><button class=" btn btn-success mr-2 frftr-grn" id="navbtn">Add</button></a>
```

**client.js (does not work):**

```
$(function () {
  $('#chkLog').click(function () {
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        window.location.href = "/add";
      }
      else {
        $('#chkLog').modal("show");
      }

  });
});
```

On server-side I have the following code:

```
app.get("/add", (req, res) => {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.render("add");
  }else{
    res.render("/")
  }  
});
```

To my knowledge I can not prompt the modal for server side. I would have to add a href for the server side get request of course. So that leaves me to conclude I either have to find a way to load the modal from server-side, or to try to check from client-side if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to trigger if else statements client-side based on if the user is authenticated, you want to have the isAuthenticated if/else statements ready in the app.get along with a boolean for your rendered page. From the client side use ejs to create clientside scripts.

***Server side:***

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        res.render("home",{logStatus:true});
    });
  }else{
        res.render("home",{logStatus:false});
    });
  }
});
```

**client EJS:**

```
  <%if(logStatus){%>
    <script>
     $('#chkLog').click(function () { 
      window.location.href = "/add"; 
     }); 
    </script>
  <%}else{%>
    <script>
    $('#chkLog').click(function () {
       $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }); 
    </script>
  <% }; %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for authentication at the time of render itself. i.e. when the user is not authenticated render `href=#` and `onClick=modalHandler` and when the user is authenticated display normal link and remove the onClick handler.
In your example when the user is authenticated the code will look like something this.

```
$(function () {
    $('#addBtn').click(function () {
        window.location.href = "/add";
    });
});
```

and when the user is not authenticated your code should look like this.

```
$(function () {
    $('#addBtn').click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    });
});
```

The logic of which code to generate has to be implemented in the `ejs` template. When you click on the button the click event will be handled on the browser so the code to display the modal has to be written on client-side and not server side.

Comment: yes, but how do i check if the user is authenticated on client-side? That's what i am having issue with. Sorry If i didn't make that part clear. :( if(isAuthenticated) does not work on the client end.

Comment: Do it on server , while rendering the template. I am assuming you are using ejs for that.

Comment: alright i do have that part handled serverside but how do i trigger the modal from the server-side? I'm honestly not seeing the full picture for what you are describing sorry.I will edit my initial post further for more detail.

Comment: @VI11age_ID10T I have updated the answer, see if this make sense to you.

Comment: Yes, in if-else block

Comment: alright i think i understand what you're getting at, but now im having some weird issue I'll pull up a thing in pastebin. https://pastebin.com/CCdamcQr

for some reason though im having issues with jquery not being recognized on the second function for $('#chkLog') not sure why yet. Thank again for all this help i've been stuck on this problem for half a week man.

Comment: im an idiot. i removed the unecessary ejs brackets. Now i gotta fix my logstatus conditional.  pastebin.com/CCdamcQr

Comment: Got it running! Thank you so much Vikash! You pulled my butt outta the fire with this! I'm writing up my answer to make this useful for future generations.